Is it economically advisable to replace cassette and chain to protect the crankset?
My chain and cassette are both pretty worn after 2000 and 5700km respectively. My drivetrain is all steel, and the relative price of my parts chain-cassette-crankset are about 0.7-1-7 and front chainrings alone are not replaceable. Things are running smoothly, but I do get the classic chain riding up on the cassette in the rear when inspecting it. The chain is about 0.8%-0.9% elongated and it seems to be too late to put a new chain on it.
I do get some pleasure out of seeing how long I can make parts last, and don't like to throw away working parts. My question is the reasonableness/economics of just running it until I get issues or to replace cassette and chain now to prevent wearing down the chainrings/crankset.

Out of curiosity, what crankset do you have that is worth so much yet does not feature replaceable chainrings? Also, see this question for related info: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/72287/what-would-happen-if-i-don-t-replace-worn-drivetrain-components.

Shimano 8speed. It's not fancy, but expensive relative to the other parts.

It has riveted chainrings, right? Isn't it possible to drill out the rivets and use proper new chainrings with bolts?

BTW, I'm surprised your chains and cassette are not lasting longer. Are you measuring chain wear with a good tool like Park Tool CC4?

@Michael Almost anything is possible, but it is not a realistic option for me or most people. Huge quads, riding hard through salty winters on Shimano 8sp. No, but I measure the entire chain off the bike relative to a new chain. It doesn't give an excact measurment, but it is good enough for my purpose and I doubt it overestimates the wear.

It seems odd that the front chainrings alone can't be replaced if this is a decent crankset. Perhaps the next step after the chainrings get worn out would be to get a crankset where you can replace the chainrings.
For performance drivetrains, you would definitely want to replace the chain the second it hits the specified wear mark (0.5 for 11s chains and above). For Shimano, the costs of the chains and cassette are pretty close - the MSRPs of the R8000 cassettes and chains are (I believe) US$94 and $42, but the MSRPs for the chainrings are a lot more - $180 for big rings and $22 for small rings. Even so, I would want to spare the big ring any wear.
On SRAM and Campagnolo, the expensive cassettes push the economic breakpoint even more in favor of replacing the chain early.
In sum, letting chains run beyond their specified replacement point is a false economy. As an alternative, you could invest more effort in keeping your chain clean and selecting a good lubricant. A bunch of people push wax lubricants these days, but if you don't want to bother with that, there are excellent drip lubricants available. I consider Zero Friction Cycling to be credible, and his test data point to Silca Synergetic and Rex Black Diamond as the top 2 standard drip lubes. Nix Frix Shun has also been a highly recommended lube. Boeshield T9 aerosol is also highly rated for a wet lube, which I found surprising because their T9 drip lube had a propensity to attract dirt. I think the author was also surprised.
Many of the highly rated lubes on Zero Friction's site are expensive. Very understandably, people might question if they need that expensive a lubricant. I would definitely have done so earlier on in my cycling career! However, lubricant can last for a long time. You're aiming for 1-2 drops per roller, and while that seems like a lot of drops, it's not a lot of volume. Additionally, the additional chain lifespan from a good lube can be significant. Therefore, I'd advise that focusing on the lubricant price is potentially a false economy.

It's not a decent crankset. But it does the job. I really can't say I notice much difference between different types of lubrication in terms of wear. Perhaps dirt/riding conditions/toque just dwarfs any effect this has.

OK, perhaps consider upping your cleaning regimen first. Then you could consider changing lube, if you buy the testing.

I haven't tried all lubes, but the sillca you referenced for instance costs almost the same as a new cassette & chain combined. I'd rather replace both a bit earlier than spend that amount on lube :\

With respect, that's a common reaction, but I feel like this is potentially false economy as well. A bottle of lubricant is likely to last quite a long time. I am going 4 years on a large bottle of their wax lube + a bag of their hot melt (used in combo), and I'm still got half the solid wax and 1/4 the drip wax left.

I'm not convinced the mentioned lube so superior as to defend it's price. But I might be wrong. Muc-off dry which was the winner of a nicely done YouTube test is unfortunately not on the zero-friction site. I've tried other ones as well, and I don't get less kms than lots of people out there on my 8sp chains/cassettes.

If you examine Zero Friction's controlled test methodology and his cost to run modeling, it may be useful to you.
